# dropdown value is save in mysql database via soap webservices in android

Tags: android, mysql, web-services, jdbc, android-spinner

I wish to insert dropdown value in mysql database via soap webservice in android...if i have to change the dropdown value from my android app means that update value also save in mysql database...how is to do.please help me.

this is my webservice code:

```
public class Insertion {

public String insertData(String userName,String userPassword){

try{

 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/androidlogin","root","");
 PreparedStatement statement =  con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO user(status) VALUES ('"+userName+"');");
 int result = statement.executeUpdate();
  }

   catch(Exception exc){
   System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
     }

   return "Insertion successfull!!";
     }

     }
```

this is my android code:

```
    public class InsertionExample extends Activity{
    private final String NAMESPACE = "http://ws.retailer.com";
private final String URL = "http://192.168.1.168:8085/Retailer/services/GetCurrentDateTime?wsdl";
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://ws.retailer.com/insertData";
private final String METHOD_NAME = "insertData";
Button btninsert;
private Spinner spnMusketeers;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    btninsert = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_insert);  
    btninsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
         insertValues();
        }
    });
}

public void insertValues(){
Spinner userName = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnMusketeers);
    String user_Name = userName.getContext().toString();

 spnMusketeers = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnMusketeers);
 List<String> lsMusketeers = new ArrayList<String>();
 lsMusketeers.add("Q");
 lsMusketeers.add("C");
 lsMusketeers.add("P");
 lsMusketeers.add("I");
 lsMusketeers.add("F");

 ArrayAdapter<String> aspnMusketeers = 
   new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, 
    lsMusketeers);
 aspnMusketeers.setDropDownViewResource
    (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
 spnMusketeers.setAdapter(aspnMusketeers);

  // Set up a callback for the spinner
   spnMusketeers.setOnItemSelectedListener(
 new OnItemSelectedListener() {
     public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) { }

     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, 
      int position, long id)  {
         SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
         PropertyInfo unameProp =new PropertyInfo();
         unameProp.setName("spnMusketeers");//Define the variable name in the web service method
         unameProp.setValue(status);//Define value for fname variable
         unameProp.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable
         request.addProperty(unameProp);//Pass properties to the variable



         SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
         envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
         HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

         try{
          androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
             SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

             TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
             result.setText(response.toString());

      }
      catch(Exception e){

      } 
       // Code that does something when the Spinner value changes
     }
 });

  } 

  }
```

if i have to select the value from spinner after click the insert button means it is not inserted.the app is force closed...please review my code and give me correct solution for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below code for this insert function:

```
String selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
```